# How to ignore invalid requests - Apache

Tags: apache, tomcat7

Is there any way to configure Apache to programatically examine a request and cancel the response if the request is invalid. I mean, my intention is to skip responding and just disconnect the client. I'm currently developing a fault-tolerance server fronted by Apache which needs to (stakeholder requirement) ignore answering requests which aren't authorize (I can't even send 401). If I can't use Apache, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: tbh, you might want to discuss this with your stakeholders. You probably have an application somewhere behind your webserver. This application should be the one determining validity of a request and therefore is the one who should do the disconnect, not your webserver. Right?

Comment: Thanks for replying! Yes, you're right but I can't disconnect or cancel a response easily from within my application. It's running on JBoss, therefore the app server is consistent and always generates a response (with an error code). I couldn't find a way of -just- killing the socket, cancelling the response, etc. Any help will be more than helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuation of above comments ...

I dont know how much control you have in JBoss over headers and output sent to the browser, but you can mimic an closed/aborted request like this. From within an application.

Send these Headers, flush and stop all output:

```
HTTP/1.0 204 No Content
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
```

For example, this is the recommended method the Amazon API suggests as a response to any call that does not want a response.

Comment: Thanks again! That looks like the right approach. However, my stakeholder wants me to disconnect the user (basically just close the connection / socket). I know it can't be done, so I will consider your answer as correct unless someone else point out how to do it. Thanks!